# Pick out stuff from site?

Tags: c#, web-scraping, bing-api

Is there a way, using C#.Net, to basically use something like http://www.bing.com/images/search?q=microsoft&form=QBIL&qs=n&sk=&sc=8-4, extract all the images from it, and put it into a file?

Comment: @Ani I'm just trying to use it as an example... but thanks for the warning.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [HTML Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) and its `HTMLWeb` class to parse a web page.

Comment: Sorry, i'm a novice programmer. Can you elaborate on how I would do that?

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to do it a bit cleaner then go for bing API its the best way to do it.
In its JSON/XML/SOAP response you will get url to each Image in the result, You can retrive those images in a Loop or more better in a LINQ query.

Check out this [PDF](http://www.bing.com/developers/s/API%20Basics.pdf) which tell you the basic for get going.

Here is an example of how you can do it. First [get an APPID](http://www.bing.com/developers/createapp.aspx) that allow you to make API Queries then.

make a request like this

```
string url = "http://api.search.live.net/xml.aspx?Appid={0}&sources={1}&query={2}";
string completeUri = String.Format(url, AppId, "image", "microsoft");
HttpWebRequest webRequest = null;
webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(completeUri);
HttpWebResponse webResponse = null;
webResponse = (HttpWebResponse)webRequest.GetResponse();
XmlReader xmlReader = null;
xmlReader = XmlReader.Create(webResponse.GetResponseStream());
```

then create a class that will keep the returned data.

```
public class LiveSearchResultImage
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string URI { get; set; }
    public string ImageURI { get; set; }
    public string ThumbnailURI { get; set; }
}
```

and then retrive the data from response using a LINQ query.

```
XDocument data = XDocument.Load(xmlReader);
IEnumerable<XNode> nodes = null;
nodes = data.Descendants(XName.Get("Results", IMAGE_NS)).Nodes();
if (nodes.Count() > 0)
{
    var results = from uris in nodes
    select new LiveSearchResultImage
    {
    URI =
    ((XElement)uris).Element(XName.Get("Url", IMAGE_NS)).Value,
    Title =
    ((XElement)uris).Element(XName.Get("Title", IMAGE_NS)).Value,
    ThumbnailURI =
    ((XElement)uris).Element(XName.Get("Thumbnail", IMAGE_NS)).Value,
    };
    return results;
}
```